# Какая из этих функций поддерживает полиморфизм

Tags: python, функции, полиморфизм

```
def test1 (x, y):
    return x * y

def test2 (x):
    arr = []
    arr.append(x)
    return arr

def test3 ():
    print('test')
```

Comment: Горячо поддерживает или последовательно поддерживает?

Comment: Полиморфизм - это же про классы, а не про функции, не?

Comment: да в принципе они все поддерживают

Comment: Я думаю, если привести определение полиморфизма, а еще пояснить, какие трудности возникают с применением определения в конкретной ситуации, то минусов будет меньше. Тут не все знакомы с [определением](https://bit.ly/2ZsN1g9) в широком смысле `Полиморфизм в языках программирования и теории типов — способность функции обрабатывать данные разных типов`

Answer (score 2):

Ваш вопрос неясный — вы вероятно имеете в виду *«Которая из этих функций может работать с параметрами любых типов?»*

Такой является функция `test2()`, потому что она возвращает одночленный список с элементом—параметром, и *такой список возможно создать с параметром любого типа.*

Comment: Если функция `может работать с параметрами разных типов` - то это и есть [полиморфизм](https://bit.ly/2ZsN1g9).

Comment: `test1()` перемноэит Integer и как минимум Float, это не считается?